# Is there a way I can keep the option I selected in the display?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the below drop-down list and would like the month I click on to hold, but as soon as I click Submit it reverts back to January even though its showing me data for a different month.
is there a way the month I'm viewing can be displayed?

The dropdown code

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('timesheet.filter') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Select Month:</label>
                <select name="month" class="form_control">
                    <option value="01">January</option>
                    <option value="02">February</option>
                    <option value="03">March</option>
                    <option value="04">April</option>
                    <option value="05">May</option>
                    <option value="06">June</option>
                    <option value="07">July</option>
                    <option value="08">August</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>

                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Thank you for any help you can give

Added  (I realise they are not in date order, this will be another thing to work on)  :/

[image: This is the table I'm trying to edit, as you can see the data for June loads, but the drop box goes back to Jan, id like it to stay on which ever month I have loaded]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear,

you can try the selected option for the default value as

```html
<select name="month" class="form_control">
    <option value="01" >January</option>
    <option value="02" >February</option>
    <option value="03" >March</option>
    <option value="04" >April</option>
    <option value="05" >May</option>
    <option value="06" Selected>June</option>
    <option value="07" >July</option>
    <option value="08" >August</option>
    <option value="09" >September</option>
    <option value="10" >October</option>
    <option value="11" >November</option>
    <option value="12" >December</option>
</select>
```

if you are redirecting with your old valuers when there is a validation error
You can try out the old function as

```html
<select name="month" class="form_control">
    <option value="01" {{ old("month")=="01"?'selected':'' }}>January</option>
    <option value="02" {{ old("month")=="02"?'selected':'' }}>February</option>
    <option value="03" {{ old("month")=="03"?'selected':'' }}>March</option>
    <option value="04" {{ old("month")=="04"?'selected':'' }}>April</option>
    <option value="05" {{ old("month")=="05"?'selected':'' }}>May</option>
    <option value="06" {{ old("month")=="06"?'selected':'' }}>June</option>
    <option value="07" {{ old("month")=="07"?'selected':'' }}>July</option>
    <option value="08" {{ old("month")=="08"?'selected':'' }}>August</option>
    <option value="09" {{ old("month")=="09"?'selected':'' }}>September</option>
    <option value="10" {{ old("month")=="10"?'selected':'' }}>October</option>
    <option value="11" {{ old("month")=="11"?'selected':'' }}>November</option>
    <option value="12" {{ old("month")=="12"?'selected':'' }}>December</option>
</select>
```

or else if you have to get the current month selected

```php
<?php
    $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $month = $now->format('m');
?>
```

```html
<select name="month" class="form_control">
    <option value="1" {{ $month=="1"?'selected':'' }}>January</option>
    <option value="2" {{ $month=="2"?'selected':'' }}>February</option>
    <option value="3" {{ $month=="3"?'selected':'' }}>March</option>
    <option value="4" {{ $month=="4"?'selected':'' }}>April</option>
    <option value="5" {{ $month=="5"?'selected':'' }}>May</option>
    <option value="6" {{ $month=="6"?'selected':'' }}>June</option>
    <option value="7" {{ $month=="7"?'selected':'' }}>July</option>
    <option value="8" {{ $month=="8"?'selected':'' }}>August</option>
    <option value="9" {{ $month=="9"?'selected':'' }}>September</option>
    <option value="10" {{ $month=="10"?'selected':'' }}>October</option>
    <option value="11" {{ $month=="11"?'selected':'' }}>November</option>
    <option value="12" {{ $month=="12"?'selected':'' }}>December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will hold June which is a step closer, thank you! , but  I want it to hold any month,  lets say I click on December and load the values from there, but the dropdown option reverts back to Jan (or now June with your code)  I will keep playing about

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```
@php 



 $months=[
"01"=>"January",
"02"=>"February",
"03"=>"March",
"04"=>"April",
"05"=>"May",
"06"=>"June",
"07"=>"July",
"08"=>"August",
"09"=>"September",
"10"=>"October",
"11"=>"November",
"12"=>"December"
];

@endphp

<select name="month" class="form_control">
@foreach($months as $key=>$value)
   <option value="{{$key}}" {{(old('month') ==$key ? 'selected' : '')}}>{{$value}}</option>
@endforeach
           
</select>
```

Comment: Although the drop down still reverts back to January, this is a neater code so have changed to this, thank you !

Comment: try passing $month =01 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

[Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com) is your friend here:

```html
<select name="month" class="form-control">
  @for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
  @php $selected = (old('month', $month) == $i ? 'selected' : ''); @endphp
  <option value="{{ $i }}" {{ $selected }}>
    {{ (new Carbon\Carbon())->month($i)->format('F') }}
  </option>
  @endfor
</select>
```

Using `$i` to represent the Month (1-12), you can construct and format a `Carbon` instance to return "January" through "December". Remeber to keep your code "DRY" - **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.

This requires you to either set `$month` in the `GET` request, or perform a `return back()->withInput()` on the `POST` request. For example:

`ExampleController.php`

```php
public function show(){ 
  $month = 1;
  // $month = Carbon::now()->format('m')
  // $month = Model::first()->month;
  // etc.

  return view('view')->with(['month' => $month]);
}

public function store(Request $request){
  // Do something with `$request->input('month') ...

  return back()->withInput();
  // return redirect()->route('path_to_view_method');
  // etc.
}
```

Doing the above will ensure a pre-selected value (either 1, the current month or the stored month from the Database) will be selected when you load the view with the dropdown.

Comment: I've tried all methods posted (thank you so much) but I still can't get it to hold, the daft thing is in another view I can get a different select option to hold the selected value, but for some reason, I cant with this, maybe because the previous one is reading its list from a migration and this is not?